# UE4 Playback time in C++

Tags: c++, audio, unreal-engine4

I'm working on Sound Handling lately, but I've encountered big problem.
What I want to achieve, is to get Playback Time(how long sound has been played till now for example i have 10 sec sound and i pasue it after 3 seconds so i should get value of 7 back). This is my current function:

```
float MyAudioClass::GetPlaybackTime(UAudioComponent* AComponent, float &PlaybackTime)
{
    if (AComponent)
    {
        FAudioDevice* AudioDevice = AComponent->GetAudioDevice();
        if (AudioDevice)
        {
            FActiveSound* ActiveSound = AudioDevice->FindActiveSound(AComponent->GetAudioComponentID());
            if (ActiveSound)
            {
                PlaybackTime = ActiveSound->PlaybackTime;
                return PlaybackTime;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However when I'm trying to use it, whole engine crashes and  I recieve this error:

```
Assertion failed: IsInAudioThread()
myaudioclass.cpp:173
myaudioclass.h:41
```

Error lines are in order:

```
if (ActiveSound) //173
    GENERATED_BODY() //41
```

What Am I doing wrong here? If someone is that kind to help me i would really appreciate that :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Graeme said, you have to run the code in the audio thread.

Here is a snippet used in `AudioComponent.cpp`:

```
if (FAudioDevice* AudioDevice = GetAudioDevice())
{
    const uint64 MyAudioComponentID = AudioComponentID;
    FAudioThread::RunCommandOnAudioThread([AudioDevice, MyAudioComponentID, InName, InFloat]()
    {
        FActiveSound* ActiveSound = AudioDevice->FindActiveSound(MyAudioComponentID);
        if (ActiveSound)
        {
            ActiveSound->SetFloatParameter(InName, InFloat);
        }
    }, GET_STATID(STAT_AudioSetFloatParameter));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the sound system is playing in a seperate thread to the Game Thread.  So when you make the call you are executing the code in the wrong thread.

If when you start the sound, in the same call you perform the `FindActiveSound` call (assuming you don't get a reference to FActiveSound returned), and store this in a variable of your MyAudioClass.

Then when you make your call to retrieve the playback time, use this stored reference to the FActiveSound object, to retrieve the PlaybackTime.

HTH